# logstash error with kerberos while inserting to webhdfs from kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kerberos, webhdfs

We have logstash pipeline  as below to read from kafka topic to webhdfs

- Input = kafka topic
- Output = webhdfs

I have extracted from  source (logstash-6.2.4.tar.gz) and did the testing

Our hadoop cluster is kerberos enabled cluster
I am getting below error while executing pipeline .

```
[user@hostname]$ bin/logstash -f /datan1/logstash-6.2.4/bin/pipeline.conf

Sending Logstash's logs to /datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-05-04T15:04:06,566][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow",
:directory=>"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-05-04T15:04:06,607][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache",
:directory=>"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-05-04T15:04:07,880][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file
because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-05-04T15:04:09,193][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.4"}
[2018-05-04T15:04:10,034][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-05-04T15:04:15,906][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>32,
"pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-05-04T15:04:19,373][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main",
:plugin=>"#<LogStash::OutputDelegator:0x100380a9
@namespaced_metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::NamespacedMetric:0x5ba440f8
@metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::Metric:0x2affe8ea
@collector=#<LogStash::Instrument::Collector:0x4954cc3d @agent=nil,
@metric_store=#<LogStash::Instrument::MetricStore:0x45de0b76
@store=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fac entries=4 default_proc=nil>,
@structured_lookup_mutex=#<Mutex:0x41868944>,
@fast_lookup=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb0 entries=63
default_proc=nil>>>>, @namespace_name=[:stats, :pipelines, :main,
:plugins, :outputs,
:d4fc8a80f489c5060bccfb1317f8c420c21a88b6fd6135075b8f7131c356cf29]>,
@metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::NamespacedMetric:0x5c5513c0
@metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::Metric:0x2affe8ea
@collector=#<LogStash::Instrument::Collector:0x4954cc3d @agent=nil,
@metric_store=#<LogStash::Instrument::MetricStore:0x45de0b76
@store=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fac entries=4 default_proc=nil>,
@structured_lookup_mutex=#<Mutex:0x41868944>,
@fast_lookup=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb0 entries=63
default_proc=nil>>>>, @namespace_name=[:stats, :pipelines, :main,
:plugins, :outputs]>,
@out_counter=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2
-  name: out value:0, @strategy=#<LogStash::OutputDelegatorStrategies::Legacy:0x636843ca
@worker_count=1, @workers=[<LogStash::Outputs::WebHdfs
host=>\"xxx.xx.xx.xx\", port=>50070,
path=>\"/user/logstash/ocs_cdr_data/dt=%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/ocs_cdr_data-%{+HH}.log\",
user=>\"user\", use_kerberos_auth=>true,
kerberos_keytab=>\"/home/user/user.keytab\",
id=>\"d4fc8a80f489c5060bccfb1317f8c420c21a88b6fd6135075b8f7131c356cf29\", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Line
id=>\"line_80e1b3a5-9a38-4674-85cc-c7e519b32c2e\",
enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\", delimiter=>\"\\n\">,
workers=>1, standby_host=>false, standby_port=>50070,
idle_flush_time=>1, flush_size=>500, open_timeout=>30,
read_timeout=>30, use_httpfs=>false, single_file_per_thread=>false,
retry_known_errors=>true, retry_interval=>0.5, retry_times=>5,
compression=>\"none\", snappy_bufsize=>32768,
snappy_format=>\"stream\", use_ssl_auth=>false>],
@worker_queue=#<SizedQueue:0x3a5f35e0>>,
@in_counter=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2
-  name: in value:0, @id=\"d4fc8a80f489c5060bccfb1317f8c420c21a88b6fd6135075b8f7131c356cf29\", @time_metric=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2
-  name: duration_in_millis value:0, @metric_events=#<LogStash::Instrument::NamespacedMetric:0x25b6080a
@metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::Metric:0x2affe8ea
@collector=#<LogStash::Instrument::Collector:0x4954cc3d @agent=nil,
@metric_store=#<LogStash::Instrument::MetricStore:0x45de0b76
@store=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fac entries=4 default_proc=nil>,
@structured_lookup_mutex=#<Mutex:0x41868944>,
@fast_lookup=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb0 entries=63
default_proc=nil>>>>, @namespace_name=[:stats, :pipelines, :main,
:plugins, :outputs,
:d4fc8a80f489c5060bccfb1317f8c420c21a88b6fd6135075b8f7131c356cf29,
:events]>, @output_class=LogStash::Outputs::WebHdfs>",
:error=>"uninitialized constant GSSAPI::GssApiError::LibGSSAPI\nDid
you mean?  GSSAPI", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x773117db run>"}
[2018-05-04T15:04:19,411][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main",
:exception=>#<NameError: uninitialized constant
GSSAPI::GssApiError::LibGSSAPI
Did you mean?  GSSAPI>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3343:in `const_missing'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/exceptions.rb:9:in
`<class:GssApiError>'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/exceptions.rb:7:in
`<module:GSSAPI>'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/exceptions.rb:6:in
`<main>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955:in `require'",
"uri:classloader:/jruby/kernel/kernel.rb:13:in `require_relative'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/client_v1.rb:1:in
`<main>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955:in `require'",
"uri:classloader:/jruby/kernel/kernel.rb:13:in `require_relative'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/client_v1.rb:6:in
`<main>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955:in `require'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in
`require'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/webhdfs-0.8.0/lib/webhdfs/client.rb:1:in
`<main>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955:in `require'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in
`require'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-webhdfs-3.0.6/lib/logstash/outputs/webhdfs_helper.rb:12:in
`load_module'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-webhdfs-3.0.6/lib/logstash/outputs/webhdfs.rb:135:in
`register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/legacy.rb:17:in
`register'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:42:in
`register'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in
`register_plugin'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in
`block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in
`each'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in
`register_plugins'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:730:in
`maybe_setup_out_plugins'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:363:in
`start_workers'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290:in
`run'",
"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:250:in
`block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x773117db run>"}
[2018-05-04T15:04:19,465][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main,
:action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could
not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<NameError: uninitialized constant
GSSAPI::GssApiError::LibGSSAPI
```

My pipeline config as below

```
    [username@hostname]$ cat /datan1/logstash-6.2.4/bin/pipeline.conf
    input {
    kafka{
    group_id => "logstash"
    jaas_path => "/usr/logstash/"
    sasl_kerberos_service_name => "kafka"
    kerberos_config => "/etc/krb5.conf"
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
    topics => ["ocs_cdr_data"]
    codec => "json"
    bootstrap_servers => "ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092,ip4:9092"
    type => "ocs_cdr_data"
    }}
    output {

      webhdfs {
        host => "ip.xx.xx.x"                 # (required)
        port => 50070                       # (optional, default: 50070)
        path => "/user/logstash/ocs_cdr_data/dt=%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/ocs_cdr_data-%{+HH}.log"  # (required)
        user => "username"                       # (required)
    use_kerberos_auth => "true"
    kerberos_keytab => "/home/username/username.keytab"
      }
    }
```

jaas.conf as below

```
KafkaClient {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
            useKeyTab=true
            storeKey=true
            useTicketCache=true
            renewTicket=true
            serviceName="kafka
            keyTab="/home/username/username.keytab"
            principal="username@DOMAIN";
    };
    ~
```

pipeline.conf validated successfully  as below

```
[username@hostname] $  bin/logstash -f /datan1/logstash-6.2.4/bin/pipeline.conf --config.test_and_exit
Sending Logstash's logs to /datan1/logstash-6.2.4/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-05-04T15:59:45,177][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-05-04T15:59:45,195][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/datan1/logstash-6.2.4/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-05-04T15:59:45,709][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
Configuration OK
[2018-05-04T15:59:48,478][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
```

======

```
[cat  /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
default_realm = domain.domainGSM.COM
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
udp_preference_limit = 1
kdc_timeout = 9000
ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
[realms]
domain.domainGSM.COM = {
kdc = hofdmc04.domain.domaingsm.com
admin_server = hofdmc04.domain.domaingsm.com
}
```

==========

kindly assist

Comment: Please edit the post to add the /etc/krb5.conf as well.

Comment: Hi Heron , added krb5.conf as well

Comment: I see a problem. In /etc/krb5.conf, your *default_realm = domain.domainGSM.COM*. But in jaas.conf you have *principal="username@DOMAIN"*. I think you need to change that to: *"username@DOMAIN.DOMAINGSM.COM"*

Comment: I did that change  , still same error as below......................................................."Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<NameError: uninitialized constant GSSAPI::GssApiError::LibGSSAPI
"

Comment: Kindly Update me on this